# Cannot upgrade a system from EF 4.3.1 to 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Background: 
I have upgraded my system from Entity Framework 4.3.1 to 5, and moved from VS 2010 to VS 2012.
I have also upgraded to MVC4 from MVC3.
I use EF Migrations Code First.

All this is working perfectly on my machine, and therefore I try to upgrade my test server with the new code.

First I installed .Net 4.5 on the server, without incident (including all subsequent windows updates). 
Then I verified that the system continues to run on the upgraded server, which it does.

Then I build a deployment package with the new "Publish..." wizard in VS2012. Here I decide not to check the checkbox called "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)", because I want to do this with my own explicit call to migrate.exe, directly after install.

Now, I try to upgrade the test system. The deployment works without problems, but when I try to run the call to migrate.exe I first get the message:

"No pending code-based migrations." then there comes a big red text block, stating that:

"ERROR: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration."

And when I try to use the system, this call to verify the validity of the database returns false:
context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)
This is not accepted by my system, and it shuts down.

Then I revert to my previous package, after replacing the CreatedOn column in __MigratHistory, and the system works like a charm again.
Below is the sql sript i use to revert...

```
alter table dbo.__MigrationHistory
add CreatedOn datetime null
go

Update s
Set s.CreatedOn = CAST(SUBSTRING(s.MigrationId, 1, 8) as datetime) + CAST(SUBSTRING(s.MigrationId, 9, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(s.MigrationId, 11, 2) as time),
s.ProductVersion = '4.3.1'
from dbo.__MigrationHistory s
```

Any sugestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

do changes in Configuration.cs file ==>

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = **true**;
    }
```